# Passing Checkbox selected value to modal popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to send email to multiple users based on checkboxs selected.

In Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ChkBxSendMail(int[] check)
        {
            return View();
        }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChkBxSendMail(int[] check, Profile profile, mail email)
    {
        foreach (var item in check)
        {
            var dbprofile = db.Profile.Single(p => p.ProfileId == item);
            string Emailid = dbprofile.EmailId;

            //var mailid = from p in db.Profile where p.ProfileId == id select p.EmailId;

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("xxxx");
            msg.From = fromAddress;
            msg.To.Add(Emailid);
            msg.Subject = email.Subject;
            msg.Body = email.Body;
            msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxx", "xxxx");
            client.Send(msg);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Profiles", "profile");
    }
```

In View:

"input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<%: item.ProfileId %>" /> "
for a table..

**Problem**
   Unable to pass check box selected  value to action result.

Answer (score 1):

can you show all view code did you use html.beginform try this

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ChkBxSendMail", "here controler name", FormMethod.Post))
 { %>  
<table>
<tr> </tr> 
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
<tr> <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<%: item.ProfileId %>" /> </td>
<td> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) %> </td>
<td> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName) %> </td> 
 </tr> 
 </table>
 <input type="submit"/>
<% } %>
<%} %>
```

Comment: No, It checkbox is in a table

Comment: <table>
        <tr>
                              
        </tr>   
    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>            
                <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<%: item.ProfileId %>" /> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName) %>
            </td>         
        </tr>
    <% } %>

Comment: i edit my answer copy and paste on ur view just replace "here controler name" with your controller  hope this work

Comment: you can also use this approach this was work for me  http://forums.asp.net/t/1759844.aspx/1?saving+multiple+checkbox+data  use Young Yang Reply

Comment: whats your controler name did you change it

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are independents. You shouldn't use different checkboxes with the same name attribute.

Also, the values of your different checkboxes should be available on your controller at Request.Form["nameOfCheckbox"]